# Multiplication $ H\times P(1/x) $ in sense of distributions

Tags: analysis, distribution-theory

If $ P(1/x) $ means the principal value of $1/x$ and $ H(x) $ is the Heaviside step function is this then correct (regularization)

$$\operatorname{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(x)f(x)}{x}\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{H(x)f(x)-H(0)f(0)}{x}\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Sorry, but what is P.V?

Comment: Cauchy's principal value  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I can't understand the symbol $P.V\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(x)f(x)}{x}$. In you notation what this mean?

Comment: Multiplication by  $H(x)$ amounts to restricting the integration to half-line. This renders P.V. pointless: you just have the ordinary integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x}\,dx$ (which may or may not converge).